# Prove the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^4+y^4}{xy}=0$.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Prove the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^4+y^4}{xy}=0$.

*Attempt.* I tried to work with squeeze theorem, i.e. to find a function $h(x,y)$ (with limit $0$ at $(0,0)$) such that $|\frac{x^4+y^4}{xy}|\leqslant h(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$: $xy\neq 0$, but it didn't work. Any suggestions for the upper bound?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: wolframalpha computes this limit, giving result $0$.

Comment: This function doesn’t have a limit near the origin. Choose for instance the succession $a_n=(1/n,1/n^5)$ and compute the corresponding values through the function.

Comment: Try sending $y \to 0$ first for any non-zero value of $x$ and you can see the problem

Comment: I see it now, thank you. It is a surprize to me that wolframalpha computes this as zero.

Comment: I was sent the wrong way ;-)

Answer (score 2):

By polar coordinates we obtain an expression in the form

$$f(r\cos \theta,r\sin \theta)=r^2 g(\theta)$$

with $g(\theta)$ not bounded and this is a strong clue that limit doesn’t exist.

We also have

$$\frac{x^4+y^4}{xy} =\frac{x^3}{y}+\frac{y^3}{x}$$

and this is also a clue that limit doesn’t exist when $x^3$(or $y^3$) and $y$ (or $x$) are comparable or $y$ (or $x$) goess to zero more rapidly than $x$ (or $y$).

Indeed, by $x=y$ limit is zero but for $x=t\to 0$ and $y=t^3\to 0$

$$ \frac{x^4+y^4}{xy} =\frac{t^4+t^{12}}{t^4}\to 1$$

Answer (score 2):

First take $y=x$ as $x\to 0$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x^4}{x^2}=0$$

Then, take $y=x^3$ as $x\to 0$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^4+x^{12}}{x^4}=1$$

Therefore, the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Approaching the origin along $y=x$ gives limit of the expression as $0$ but approaching the origin via $y=x^{\frac 14}$ gives $\frac {x^3+1}{x^{\frac 14}}$, which does not have a limit as $x\to 0+$.

So the limit of the given expression does not exist.